# Trying to close a JLabel with setVisible(false) and dispose but Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dispose() from the type Window

Tags: java, jframe

Ok, so i am a beginner programmer trying to make a quiz and this code is for a screen that pops up with a tick when they get something correct i made now my plan was to use Thread.sleep(2000) to make a 2 second delay and then use .setVisible(false) or .dispose but when i try to use either of those to close it a message saying (Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisible(boolean) from the type Window). So can anyone please recommend to me any alternate way to do this where i can get the thing to close after 2 seconds either by making this work or with another method.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Correct extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {





    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Correct frame = new Correct();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public Correct() throws InterruptedException {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(650, 250, 600, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Eclipse\\Coursework2017\\src\\check-146095_960_720.png"));
    label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setBounds(104, 0, 384, 463);
    contentPane.add(label);

    Thread.sleep(2000);//To make the pop up close after 2 seconds
    Correct.(false);



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Better put code that *does* something with an object outside of constructor. The constructor is only meant for initializing an object.

```
public class Correct extends JFrame {
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public Correct() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        // ...
    }

    static void showAndClose() throws InterruptedException {
        Correct frame = new Correct();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        frame.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    showAndClose();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[your code does not compile, your question is somehow unclear]